# Console in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

after updating my Visual Studio I got a problem. I have a Windows Forms application and used a console window for debugging. Now this Window does not show up anymore. Maybe my settings from earlier got lost after updating.
This is what I have in my Main()

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

I did not change it after updating. I also tried to change the Output type from Windows Application to Console Application but it have not solved the problem.
The method to debug with Debug.WriteLine() in outputline works but I would prefer the variant with the console window. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The Output Window in a WinForm application works as the Console output. With `Console.WriteLine()` you write to the Output Window (or the Immediate Window, depending on the VS configuration). Setup with `Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window`. Also, `General Settings -> Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window`

Comment: For future reference: Please do not post a new question where the content is an updated version of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802650/output-window-not-opening-in-visual-studio) of yours. Instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64802650/edit) the original question with the new content. This will place it into a reopen queue and if the edits were sufficient enough the question will be re-opened

Comment: Unfortunately the answers from the other questions do not help me. I have already tried. I do not get what changed after the update. Before the update I just changed the output type to console and it worked. I had the 2017 and now I updated to 2019.

Comment: @Kathrin, as usual, the above solutions can solve your problem.  If these can't solve your problem, I suggest that you can post your question in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).